# convert TEXT dd/mm/yyyy in SQL column to DATE YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I would love to know the best way to handle data that has been inputted incorrectly as dd/mm/yyyy into a sql database as TEXT and to have it converted into a new column of the table with the datatype as DATE so it is actually stored as yyyy-mm-dd.

Existing text date column name is called "olddate" with an empty column created called "truedate" to house the new data. Each row has the date field, but none are able to be sorted correctly because of this issue.

Any ideas how I can slice and dice the current date into a new DATE field friendly version?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is style 103.  So use:

```
select convert(date, col, 103)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, though it is saying the following: `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1`
`Invalid column name 'OldDate'.`

Comment: OldDate isn't even in his answer @cloudseeker  but that error is pretty self explanatory

Comment: @scsimon The column with the date currently in it is called OldDate

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Oracle? If so, TO_DATE is what you want. You can take in a string that represents a date and convert it to a date using the format you pass it.

Comment: Sorry, SQL server... I thought it had saved that tag.

Comment: Then Gordon's answer is the one you want.